# CvInvoke.cvSmooth gone since emgu cv 3?

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am working with Emgu CV 3.1 in a C# Project.

Looking for a way to smooth images I found [cvSmooth](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.3.0/document/html/5bdae109-2a3d-0f2f-f0f3-a973ca9498cb.htm) which allows a selection which smoothing algorithm to use. In IDE I can see methods like `CvInvoke.Blur` or `CvInvoke.GaussianBlur` but there is no cvSmooth or a similar method. Is it simply gone with V3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find it as well , it seems like the  original algorithms have now been split into different functions namely :

- CvInvoke.MedianBlur
- CvInvoke.Blur
- CvInvoke.GaussianBlur
- CvInvoke.BilateralFilter

Alternatively,you can find the same methods as part of [Image "<"TColor , TDepth ">"](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/a8929aab-99c5-79cf-385c-dcec7769fea1.htm) .

Funny thing is you can still find a [SmoothType](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/16bbab80-fd50-213a-ab50-88c1365b0150.htm) Enumerator, though I could not find any method whatsoever that could take it.

I guess the split happened as a result from 2.4.10 to 3 version migration.

Comment: Noticed those too. Using SmoothType its pretty simple to recreate the functionality of cvSmooth - but it would be pretty useless if SmoothType disappears in next version too. By the way: is Image<TColor,TDepth> still good to use? Because it looks like everything is altered to Mat, like it happened to [Capture.QueryFrame](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/8dfb0679-4c54-4f17-37ba-7218cbd28e67.htm) .

Comment: Though Image type can still be used as of now , it is recommended that you develop your applications using the new Mat , as Image type will be discontinued  in future OpenCV versions, and hence , Emgu. Better do those prorams future-proof